# How do macros work in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I would like to know how do macros work in Objective-C, how does the compiler interpret them ,what makes them different from a regular function. Also, how are they able to access `__LINE__`, `__FILE__`, `_cmd` and most curious `self` (without passing it to them) in the current context?

Comment: If you're interested in how `_cmd` and `self` work, there's a pretty good explanation in [this article on CocoaWithLove](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/what-does-it-mean-when-you-assign-super.html) by Matt Gallagher. It's a recommended read.

Comment: Yep! Even though they look like macros, `_cmd` and `self` aren't (but `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` are!). This can be a little bit confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macros differ from a regular function because they are processed as *text* not as *code*.

Macro expansion is done before the compiler parses your code and is language agnostic - the macro is treated the same regardless of the target language. The process is usually referred to as *macro expansion* which happens during *preprocessing*.

`__LINE__` and `__FILE__` are macros defined by the compiler, so they are just replaced by text. A macro can "access" `_cmd` and `self` if, and only if, those variables exist in the context the macro is expanded - the macro is not really *accessing* these variables, the macro is being *expanded* and the resultant *code* accesses the variables.

You can see the effect of the macro processing by selecting **Preprocess** in XCode's **Build** menu.

Here is a (strange) example to demonstrate:

```
#define BEGIN {
#define END }

int main(int argv, char *argv[])
BEGIN
    ... // body of main
END
```

which expands to the more usual:

```
int main(int argv, char *argv[])
{
    ... // body of main
}
```

Comment: Very good explanation, thanks a lot. It makes more sense now, they seem pretty useful (form my perspective, which is not a C programmer perspective), however I saw that some C programmers, try to avoid them, any idea why, what could go wrong?

Comment: I see now that in theory you could actually change the entire C/Objective-C syntax with this, not that would make any sense of course (rather than maybe write in a more common language), but still, it's possible, preprocessing is a very powerful thing I see, I'm starting to love C and Objective-C more and more...

Answer (score 5):

They work the same as they would in **pure C**.

Macros are processed by the compiler's pre-processor, as which time the compiler still has the full source code available (and by that the name of the enclosing `__FUNCTION__` or the current `__LINE__`).
You could think of Macros as some kind of advanced "text replacement" magic.

With macros you basically tell the compiler: "**Please replace this macro** of mine **with the block of source code** that I defined it with **before doing any actual compilation**."

For more information on Macros and the C preprocessor look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor

Comment: An important distinction is that macros are just text processing, so it is "Please replace this macro of mine with the block of **text** ..."

Comment: Yes, sure. I was referring to **source code**, not **byte code**, of course. Thus I wrote "text replacement" (vs. "text compilation/conversion") in the line above. Will try to make it more clear in my answer. Thanks, CRD.

Answer (score 0):

Those are specified in the C language standard and support for them is built into the compiler. See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html for a longer list of available standard macros.

Answer (score 0):

`__LINE__` and `__FUNCTION__` are provided by the compiler and expanded during preprocessing. `self` and `_cmd` are parameters implicitly passed to every ObjC method, and are part of the Objective-C language. They are not macros, just invisible parameters.

Comment: I know that they are not macros, however, only for macros `self` is in fact `self` of the callee (?)